# How to join two React Native app and share state

Tags: react-native, ios-simulator, state

I am working on a simple quiz app where you have multiple players and one host. I want to be able to work with two simulators where one simulator shows the host screen and the other shows the players screen. But the simulator have to be connected so if I change something on the host's screen, the user's screen is updated accordingly.

So essentially, I need to be able to run two separate simulators on one app. Not mirror them.

Comment: Hi @Shemal could ask with more descriptively. Do you want to share the details between two app which run on same device or two app in separate devices ?

Comment: Hi @EL173.  That was a little cryptic. I updated the question .Let me know if that makes sense or if you need more info

Answer (score 1):

The easy way : use firebase, same app, different components for host/player, where the host can read/write data on firebase and the player can only read data.
The player subscribes to changes in the firebase database and gets them instantly when the host changes something.

The hard way : configure your own WebSocket server.

The ugly way : Using a REST API. Player requests for update every X seconds. This is not instant.

Hope this helps.